# Проблема записи файла на некоторых устройствах через openOutputStream(mUri)

Tags: java, android

Я пишу написал приложение, которое открывает текстовый файл через Uri: (getContentResolver().openInputStream(mUri))

дальше после изменения текста в EditText по нажатию кнопки я пытаюсь сохранить содержимое файла по полученному Uri: (getContentResolver().openOutputStream(mUri);)

проблема в том, что на эмуляторах весь код отрабатывает, а вот когда отлаживаю на реальном устройстве (Asus ZE553KL  Android 8.0.0), то при сохранении выдает ошибку:
"**java.io.IOException: write failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)**"

Помогите пожалуйста правильно реализовать код. Спасибо!
Ниже весь код MainActivity.

```
package com.aginf.notetohelp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText mEditText;
    private Uri mUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        //////////////////////////////////////
        // Получаю Uri только при SCHEME_CONTENT
        // и сразу открываю файл и помещаю его в EditText
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.compareTo(Intent.ACTION_VIEW) == 0) {
            String scheme = intent.getScheme();
            if (scheme.compareTo(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT) == 0) {
                mUri = intent.getData();
                OpenFromUri();
            }
        }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////
    // Процедура получения содержимого файла по Uri
    private void OpenFromUri() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Boolean res;
        try{
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(mUri);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            mEditText.setText(stringBuilder.toString());

        }catch(Throwable t){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ERROR (open from Uri): "+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////
    // ПСохранение содержимого в файл по Uri
    public void onSaveClick(View view) {
        try{
            OutputStream outputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(mUri);
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
            osw.write(mEditText.getText().toString());
            osw.close();
            outputStream.close();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }catch(Throwable t){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ERROR (save from Uri):"+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.aginf.notetohelp">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:label="Note to help" android:priority="0">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.txt" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.txt" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.txt" />
                <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.txt"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Покажите свой `mUri` - чему он равен

Comment: На ASUS, где выдает ошибку: content://com.asus.filemanager.OpenFileProvider/file/sdcard/temp/index.txt                  А на эмуляторе, где все проходит:   content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/30

Comment: Похоже, что у вас в Asus дефолтным обработчиком файлов стоит стоковый Asus'овский файл менеджер. Попробуйте снять с него галочку дефолтного обработчика файлов

Comment: Да, и кстати, покажите свой манифест

Comment: Добавил манифест

Comment: По поводу дефолтного обработчика: хочется обрабатывать контент, вне зависимости от обработчика.

Comment: Проверил на реальном HONOR P9   - работает без ошибок

Comment: Насколько я могу понять, проблема заключается в том, что вы получаете `Uri` для просмотра (`ACTION_VIEW`) и тут же пытаетесь его отредактировать. Обработчик Асуса видимо понимая, что к нему обратились для просмотра - запрещает его редакцию (то есть получение `OutputStream`) - попробуйте то же самое с `ACTION_EDIT` - вдруг получится

Comment: И еще попробуйте так: `openOutputStream(mUri, "rw")`

Comment: openOutputStream(mUri, "rw")   - это уже пробовал, не работает.   ACTION_EDIT - тоже пробовал. Если использовать вместе с VIEW, то также не работает. А если использовать без VIEW, то не появляется в списке выбора "Открыть с помощью..."

Answer (score 0):

вы забыли закрыть stream, в методе OpenFromUri()

```
    private void OpenFromUri() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Boolean res;
        try{
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(mUri);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            mEditText.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
    inputStream .close(); // ДОБАВИЛ строку тут
}catch(Throwable t)
{ 
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ERROR (open from Uri): "+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); } }
```

Comment: Даже если закрывать поток (inputStream), все равно пишет туже ошибку/

Answer (score 0):

По итогам дискуссии в комментариях вижу следующий диагноз. Сначала заглянем под капот:

Ваш use-case подразумевает, что юзер через стоковый файл-менеджер (какой бы он ни был) выбирает текстовый файл и "открывает" его. При этом в зависимости от локальной ситуации конкретных настроек девайса юзер либо выбирает с помощью чего он будет открывать текстовый файл, либо открывает приложением по умолчанию - в любом случае ваш use case подразумевает, что юзер откроет его с помощью вашего приложения.

На стороне файл-менеджера происходит при этом следующее:

1) На сцену выходит `ContentProvider`, в задачу которого входит формирование `Uri` для выдачи его внешнему `Intent`'у - в данном случае вашему приложению. Поскольку речь идет об Android 8 то прямые ссылки типа `file://` запрещены, поэтому `Uri` должен быть вида `content://`

2) В зависимости от файлового менеджера провайдер может иметь вид `FileProvider` или `DocumentsProvider` и т.д.

3) В любом случае в провайдере должны быть вариации с наличием/отсутствием разрешения на редактирование, типа:

```
<provider android:authorities="list"
      android:grantUriPermissions=["true" | "false"]
      android:permission="string"
      android:readPermission="string"
      android:writePermission="string" >
</provider>
```

4) В вашем случае, очевидно, что провайдер не предоставляет разрешения на запись.

Это либо баг конкретного провайдера файлового менеджера либо фича :) То есть надо писать в поддержку/форум поставщика девайса

Другой вариант, при "вылете" `Exception` - интеллигентно сообщить юзеру - так мол и так, файл увы не поддается редактированию.

Есть еще вариант поиграться с разными видами `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, `ACTION_EDIT` и т.д. - надежды конечно мало.

Как то так.

**Update**

Вам нужен доступ к файлам через [Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider), вам надо получать доступ к файлам именно через него, а он активируется применением `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, а не `ACTION_VIEW`, только это гарантирует доступ к файлу в режиме редактирования.

Comment: Спасибо большое!  Я думаю, при наличии подобной ошибки я предложу диалог сохранения.

Comment: См. апдейт ответа